# sed - Remove previous line and current line based on pattern

Tags: sed

I want to delete the previous line and current line based on pattern match on next line

This is my  sample.txt

```
This is test line 11
This is test line 999
This is test line 12
This is test line 13
This is test line 16
This is test line 999
This is test line 17
This is test line 18
```

I want to match for pattern 999 and delete both itself and previous line

I am trying this command but i get no output

```
sed -Ene ':a;N;/999/{d;}; ba; P' sample.txt
```

Comment: sed is the best tool for doing `s/old/new/` on individual strings. That's not what you're doing here so sed wouldn't be the best tool for the job so why do you want to use sed for it when it can be done clearer, simpler, more robustly, more portable, and/or more efficiently with some other tool? You should include a case where `999` appears as the first line of your input and where it appears on 3 contiguous lines to show how you want those handled and give us something to adequately test a potential solution against.

Comment: I think this was a great question @rgd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\n.*999/d;P;D' file
```

Open a running window of two lines throughout the length of the file.

If the second line of the window contains `999` delete both lines.

Otherwise, print the first line of the window, delete the first line and repeat.

An alternative solution for line 1 or 2 or more contiguous lines containing `999`:

```
sed -n ':a;$!N;/\n.*999/{:b;n;/999/bb;ba};/999/!P;D' file
```

Comment: This one won't work if 999 is in the first line. I solved it using a special case for line 1. Not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: @AlexHarvey the OP did not specify what should happen if the first line contains `999` nor what should happen when 2 or more lines contains `999`. However see edit.

Comment: I think \n.* is not needed in the first regex?

Comment: @AlexHarvey i think that is for case to read 999 in second line only. Few questions 1. when we go from label B TO A, does the next  line to be read is line which we initially left or  it start from line where inner label B ends ? I want to know when `n` reads continuous line containing 999 and then when it go back to label A , then what will be the contents of N

Comment: It branches immediately and unconditionally like a goto statement

Comment: @AlexHarvey i  have asked another question to clear my doubt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822978/sed-how-does-next-line-counter-get-updated

Comment: For what it's worth I wrote unit tests to test my code and potong's. Agreed that `\n.*` is needed, but it's for when 999 is in the first line. My solution below handles all edge cases, so I was at least correct that the branching isn't actually required. See my unit test code [here](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/3f157cf006006fd95bc59e0a905265d9).

Answer (score 2):

tried on gnu sed

```
 sed -Ez 's/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*999\n//g' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(if ok with `awk`).

```
awk 'prev && $NF!=999{print prev ORS FNR,$0;prev="";next} $NF==999{prev=""} $NF!=999{prev=FNR FS $0}'  Input_file
```

Or if you have even number of lines and you want to take care of printing last odd even.

```
awk 'prev && $NF!=999{print prev ORS FNR,$0;prev="";next} $NF==999{prev=""} $NF!=999{prev=FNR FS $0} END{if(prev){print prev}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: I want to use sed only

Answer (score 1):

For a sed<sup>1</sup> solution, that handles all edge cases (999 in first 2 rows or consecutive rows of 999):

```
  sed '
    1{
      /999/d  # Special case needed for line 1. Delete if it contains 999.
    }
    $!N     # Append next line. $!N stops exit w/o printing at EOF.
    /999/d  # If pattern space contains 999, d & begin next cycle.
    P       # If we get to here, there is no 999. Print to first newline.
    D       # Delete to first newline.                                   
  ' FILE
```

Output:

```
This is test line 12
This is test line 13
This is test line 17
This is test line 18
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Tested on both BSD (Mac OS X) & GNU sed.

Comment: Thanks for that , can you please tell me where i am wrong with my sed if i need to use flow control

Comment: @rgd, Your script is `:a; N; /999/d; ba; P`. `N` appends next line to pattern space. Then if `/999/` `d`elete pattern space completely and begin next cycle. If not `/999/`, goto `a` anyway. So your `P` command is not reachable, which is why you get no output.

Comment: Thanks , how can i fix my code , i mean where in the code i need to put `P` ?

Answer (score 1):

With a more comprehensive sample input of:

```
$ cat file
This is test line 999
This is test line 11
This is test line 999
This is test line 12
This is test line 13
This is test line 999
This is test line 999
This is test line 999
This is test line 14
This is test line 15
This is test line 16
This is test line 999
This is test line 17
This is test line 18
```

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$NF == 999 {
    prev = ""
    next
}
{
    printf "%s", prev
    prev = $0 ORS
}
END {
    printf "%s", prev
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
This is test line 12
This is test line 14
This is test line 15
This is test line 17
This is test line 18
```

or if you favor brevity over clarity:

```
$ awk '$NF==999{p="";next} {printf "%s",p; p=$0 ORS} END{printf "%s",p}' file
This is test line 999
This is test line 11
This is test line 999
This is test line 12
This is test line 13
This is test line 999
This is test line 999
This is test line 999
This is test line 14
This is test line 15
This is test line 16
This is test line 999
This is test line 17
This is test line 18
```

Notice that the above will work even if some other part of your line than the last field contained `999` or if the last field as `9999` instead of your target `999`, it doesn't require `999` to be written/tested multiple times in the script, if you wanted to test, say, the 3rd field in the line instead of the last field you could just change `$NF` to `$3` =, if you WANTED to test the whole line for a regexp you'd just change `$NF==999` to `/999/`, it'll work even if your target string contains regexp metacharacters, and it will work in any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Comment: It's not that much simpler than my sed solution though is it? I take the portability point. Otherwise, instead of the magic `N` that appends to pattern space, you have a magic `prev = $0 ORS` that does the same as sed's `N`.

Comment: I didn't have to add comments for my code to be clearly understandable and there's nothing magic about a variable assignment. Also, unlike with seds `N`,  if we wanted to enhance to delete, say, 10 lines before the target line instead of 1 I wouldn't have to write that statement 10 times to save 10 lines I'd just make prev a 10-line array with a loop to print it and if the OP wanted to be able to use a variable number of lines specified at run time that's exactly the same solution in awk as for a static value but impossible to do in 1 sed script.

Comment: The point is there's benefits to the awk script and no benefits to the sed script. With awk: need to print a count of deleted lines stderr?  trivial. Need to test for 999 being in a specific field? trivial. Need to test for an input string (999) as literal when it contains regexp metachars? Trivial. Need to also delete lines AFTER the target line? Trivial. Need to only delete preceding lines if they contains some other string? Trivial. etc., etc.. With awk if/when  the requirements change you usually just build on what you already have while with sed it's usually either impossible or a rewrite

Comment: Oh come on, awk is just python or C or any other algol-based language with fewer language constructs, half a dozen keywords, an implicit `while read split` loop and implicit `if`s around the `condition { action }` blocks. sed on the other hand is vastly different in both syntax and semantics. wrt maintainability of a 5 line script - you don't just write a script a certain way in preparation for enhancing THAT script, you write it that way so that when the next similar task comes along you can write that next script essentially the same way but with small differences where necessary.

Comment: Writing maintainable scripts shouldn't something you decide to do when necessary, it should be what you do unless there's a pressing need not to, e.g. for performance reasons. Anyway, as I said in another thread it took me 10 years of using sed (and shell) to manipulate text before I decided to start using awk for things that were more than just `s/old/new/` and it sounds like you're just at the beginning of your own journey with that and happy to continue it so - all the best.

Comment: Maybe there's an even better approach than doing complicated text manipulation from vim? In any case, glad you've got an approach you're happy with- all the best.