# How does Next line counter get updated in sed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I am not able to understand how does sed reads next line.

He is my understanding and please correct me where i am wrong

`/pattern/p` so this  reads line by line and prints if line is matched

`N;/pattern/d` so this reads two lines together and if pattern is there then deletes both and  in next cycle does sed starts reading from Line 2 or Line3 and Line was already read by N?

`:a N; /pattern/{:b;n;/pattern/bb; ba}`

Now in above case  the inner loop. n read next line multiple times and if then go back to a. Now my question is when control go back to a then what will N read

example

This is sample file

```
line 11
line 13
line 13
line 13
line 14
line 15
line 16
```

Initially N will contain . `line 11 \n line 13` if pattern is `13` then in the inner loop `n` again reads next line and go back untill 13 is not there and then go back to `a`

Now my questions is what will be the value of `N`? will it be

`line 14 \n line line 15` . or `line 14 \n line 13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of this behaviour can be observed using the GNU debugger, `--debug`.

```
▶ data="line 11
line 13      
line 13     
line 13                  
line 14         
line 15     
line 16"
```

Output:

```
▶ gsed ':a N; /13/{:b;n;/13/bb; ba}' <<< $data                 
line 11
line 13
line 13
line 13
line 14
line 15
line 16
```

Output view in debugger:

```
▶ gsed --debug ':a N; /13/{:b; n; /13/bb; ba}' <<< $data
```

```
SED PROGRAM:
  :a
  N
  /13/ {
    :b
    n
    /13/ b b
    b a
  }
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1
PATTERN: line 11
COMMAND: :a
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: line 11\nline 13
COMMAND: /13/ {
COMMAND:   :b
COMMAND:   n
line 11
line 13
PATTERN: line 13
COMMAND:   /13/ b b
COMMAND:   :b
COMMAND:   n
line 13
PATTERN: line 13
COMMAND:   /13/ b b
COMMAND:   :b
COMMAND:   n
line 13
PATTERN: line 14
COMMAND:   /13/ b b
COMMAND:   b a
COMMAND:   :a
COMMAND:   N
PATTERN: line 14\nline 15
COMMAND:   /13/ {
COMMAND:   }
END-OF-CYCLE:
line 14
line 15
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 7
PATTERN: line 16
COMMAND:   :a
COMMAND:   N
END-OF-CYCLE:
line 16
```

> Now my question is when control go back to a then what will N read

As you can see:

```
PATTERN: line 14
COMMAND:   /13/ b b
COMMAND:   b a
COMMAND:   :a
COMMAND:   N
PATTERN: line 14\nline 15
```

So the command immediately after`ba` is `:a` and then `N`, and `N` has the effect of reading the next line of the input stream and appending it to the pattern space.

Answer (score 3):

```
:a N; /pattern/{:b;n;/pattern/bb; ba}
```

Let's make it more readable and add comments:

```
# At the start there is one line read from input
# read into pattern space

# define label with the name 'a'
:a

# append next line to pattern space
N

# Match pattern space with 'pattern'
/pattern/{
   # go here if matching successfull

   # define label 'b'
   :b

   # read the next line into pattern space
   # current pattern space is removed
   n

   # match pattern space with /pattern/
   /pattern/{

      # goto label 'b'
      bb
   }

   # goto label 'a'
   ba

}
```

> in next cycle does sed starts reading from Line 2 or Line3 and Line was already read by N?

You can't go back in input. Input has lines. `N` appends the next line from input to pattern space. Once the input is read, you can't re-read it. `d` deletes pattern space and starts cycle (ie. works kind of `n; b<label on the beginning>`).

> my question is when control go back to a then what will N read

It will branch to `:a` when the pattern is no longer matched.

```
   not
   pattern # jumps into /pattern/{ .. }
   pattern # jumps into inside /pattern/bb
   pattern
   pattern
   not # get's back to :a
```

> my questions is what will be the value of N?

`N` has no value it is a command, that appends next line from input into pattern space.

The pattern space contents after `N` command will have two lines in it. In the example you provided at first it will have `line 11\nline13` then `line14\nline15`. It's easy to see with a simple script:

```
sed -n ':a N; p; /13/{:b;n;/13/bb; ba}' <<EOF
line 11
line 13
line 13
line 13
line 14
line 15
line 16
EOF
```

All the commands explanations can be found in [man sed](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html). [This](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is a very good introduction into sed.